# Proving Lagrange's Identity with Differential Operators

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-operators

Consider the second order linear differential operators $L$ and $\bar{L}$ given by
$$
L = p(x) \frac{d^2}{dx^2} + q(x) \frac{d}{dx} + r(x), \ \ \bar{L} =  \frac{d^2}{dx^2}p(x) -
\frac{d}{dx} q(x) + r(x)
$$
Show that, for all pairs of functions $f(x), g(x)$ we have
$$
fL[g]-g\bar{L}[f] = \frac{d}{dx}( \mathcal{B}[f,g])
$$
where $\mathcal{B}[f,g]$ is some quantity that depends on $f, f', g$ and $g'$

---

So I've attempted this by just working through the expression, but I'm unable to get something that just depends on $f, f', g$ and $g'$? I'm not sure if I'm differentiating wrong or just misunderstanding the question. I have found similar things trying to understand this problem but I cannot seem to find this exact identity anywhere, only with symmetric operators, which is not the case here.  But, here's what I have:

\begin{align}
\bar{L} 
&= \frac{d^2}{dx^2}p(x) -
\frac{d}{dx} q(x) + r(x) \\ \\
&= p(x) \frac{d^2}{dx^2} + (2p'(x) - q(x))\frac{d}{dx} + (q''(x) - q'(x) + r(x))
\end{align}
So, we get
\begin{align}
fL[g]-g\bar{L}[f] 
&= fp(x)\frac{d^2 g}{dx^2} + fq(x)\frac{dg}{dx} + fr(x)g  \\
&- gp(x)\frac{d^2 f}{dx^2} - 2gp'(x)\frac{df}{dx} + gq(x)\frac{df}{dx} - gp''(x)f + gq'(x)f - gr(x)f \\ \\
&= pfg'' + qfg' + rfg - pf''g - 2p'f'g + qf'g - p''fg + q'fg - rfg \\ \\
&= pfg'' + qfg' - pf''g - 2p'f'g + qf'g - p''fg + q'fg 
\end{align}

and, I'm pretty much stuck on where to go from here...

I've just been trying to find different ways to simplify and the furthest I've got is
$$
fL[g]-g\bar{L}[f] = p \frac{d}{dx}[f'g-fg'] + q \frac{d}{dx}[fg] + g(q'f - p''f - 2p'f')
$$

But, this doesn't appear necessarily useful to me so I'm unsure quite what to do here.

Comment: Integrate by parts the obtained expression to get $\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: Grouping pfg and qfg together will make it easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The calculation becomes more manageable if we write
$$
L=L_p+L_q+L_r, \tag{1}
$$
where
$$
L_p:=p(x)\frac{d}{dx^2},\quad L_q:=q(x)\frac{d}{dx},\quad L_r:=r(x), \tag{2}
$$
and similarly for $\bar{L}$. Thus, in decreasing order of simplicity, we have
$$
fL_r[g]-g\bar{L}_r[f]=frg-grf=0, \tag{3}
$$
$$
fL_q[g]-g\bar{L}_q[f]=fqg'+g(qf)'=(qfg)', \tag{4}
$$
and
\begin{align}
fL_p[g]-g\bar{L}_p[f]&=fpg''-g(pf)''=fpg''+(fp)'g'-g'(pf)'-g(pf)'' \\
&=[(fp)g']'-[g(pf)']'=[pfg'-(pf)'g]'. \tag{5}
\end{align}
Collecting all pieces together, we finally obtain
$$
fL[g]-g\bar{L}[f]=\frac{d}{dx}[pfg'-(pf)'g+qfg]. \tag{6}
$$